# Append SQLite query result to an existing model

Tags: swift, sqlite, model

This is how I read the data:

```
func read() -> [ChatModel] {
    let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM chatoverview;"
    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    var psns = [ChatModel]()
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            let chatId = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 0)
            let partnerId = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)
            let partnerName = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 2)
            let createdDate = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 3)
            let lastMessage = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 4)
            let lastMessageDate = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 5)
            let partnerProfileImage = sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 6)
            print("read")
            print(chatId)
            psns.append(ChatModel(dictionary: ["chatId": chatId!, "partnerId": partnerId!, "partnerName": partnerName!, "createdDate": createdDate!, "lastMessage": lastMessage!, "lastMessageDate": lastMessageDate!, "partnerProfileImage": partnerProfileImage!]))
        }
    }
```

The result from print(chatId) = "Optional(0x000000010d21fd50)" and I am not sure why the result is not a string.. anyway, in my ViewController I am trying to append this data to my existing ChatModel:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class ChatModel {

var partnerId: String?
var partnerName: String?
var createdDate: Timestamp?
var lastMessage: String?
var lastMessageDate: Timestamp?
var chatId: String?
var partnerProfileimage: String?


init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    partnerId = dictionary["partnerId"] as? String
    partnerName = dictionary["partnerName"] as? String
    createdDate = dictionary["createdDate"] as? Timestamp
    chatId = dictionary["chatId"] as? String
    lastMessage = dictionary["lastMessage"] as? String
    lastMessageDate = dictionary["lastMessageDate"] as? Timestamp
    partnerProfileimage = dictionary["partnerProfileimage"] as? String
    }
}
```

Relevant code in my ViewController:

```
var test = [ChatModel]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    test = db.read()
    print(test.count) <---- 5 Items, correct number, my SQLite file also has the correct data / schema

    for x in test {
        print(x.lastMessage)
    }
```

And here is the problem. x.lastMessage is always nil.

How can I append the SQL result to my existing model?

Comment: Maybe not relevant to your issue but I would advice you to replace `*` in your query with a list of the actual column names, `SELECT chatId, partnerId,...`. It will be easier to troubleshoot your code then and clearer what is being read from the database. Also, why use a dictionary as some in-between storage, I don't see the point. Create an init method with all properties as parameters instead.

Comment: Thank you for your input Joakim